# Deployed angular 8 app gets an error on initial route urls

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

When I deploy an angular 8 app to a Google Cloud Python App Engine environment, it works great.
EXCEPT

If my App Engine domain is say https://mysuper-app.appspot.com, that is fine, but if I initially route to any routes within the app, say:

```
https://mysuper-app.appspot.com/viewfancything/237
```

I get an error result:

> Error: Not Found
>   The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

It's probably a switch or something either on the build or more probably the app.yaml for the App Engine, but any idea how I can make this work correctly?

Comment: Are you using App Engine on Standard, Flexible or Custom environment? Did you try to use [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml) ? 
You can find more information about how the requests are routed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-routed)

Comment: It's a Flex environment. Hmm... didn't know about dispatch.yaml!

Answer (score 0):

Routing is performed virtually based on Angulars Router and not based on actual files. Therefore, your configuration can't resolve the routes like `/route`. So, you have to redirect all requests to your `index.html` in order to handle these.

assuming that you already build your angular project into a `dist/project_name` folder,

write an app.yaml file on `dist/` and fill it with these:

```html
runtime: python37
handlers:
    - url: /(.*\.(js|css|svg|png)(|\.map))$
      static_files: [project_name]/\1
      upload: [project_name]/(.*)(|\.map)
    - url: /.*
      static_files: [project_name]/index.html
      upload: [project_name]/.*
```

next, deploy it with `gcloud app deploy` command from `dist/` directory